# How to remove check attribute from checkbox when click on other checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

i have two checboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some" >
<input type="checkbox" name="other" >
```

the thing i want to do that when i check one of them other one should automatically unchecked. Remember that name of both checkboxes are changed not same  . please help me . Thanx in advance

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons for this? (`<input type="radio" name="other" >`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="some"]').click(function(){
    $('input[name="other"]').removeAttr('checked');
});

$('input[name="other"]').click(function(){
    $('input[name="some"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Working sample

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="some" >
<input type="checkbox" name="other" >

<script>
$('input[name="some"]').click(function(){
    $('input[name="other"]').removeAttr('checked');
});

$('input[name="other"]').click(function(){
    $('input[name="some"]').removeAttr('checked');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Very strange, it works for me. Editing answer with working sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with radio buttons, because so you don't have to add any javascript code !
Radio buttons only allow one selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good choice to use classes on the checkboxes and from there and then just call the functions.

Comment: i didn't get you . what you want to say ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery v1.6 or higher;

```
$('input[name="some"]').click(function(){
    $('input[name="other"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

This code unchecks the 'other' checkbox when the 'some' checkbox is clicked.

Comment: can i use this $("#some") instead of $('input[name="some"]')

Comment: @Ahsan Attari: yes if you have an ID value of some then its just fine.

Comment: no, its still not working 
i tried
 .attr("checked",false)
 .prop("checked",false)
 .removeAttr("Checked")

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){

  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
  }
   $(this).prop("checked", true);

});
```